# Unable to load 'protobuf.js' when fetching Firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

Running a barebones node file:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
const http = require('http')

require("firebase/firestore");

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  serviceAccount: '...',
  projectId: '...'
});

var db = firebase.firestore();
var userRef = db.collection('...').doc('...');
```

Results in the following terminal rule

> Firestore (4.5.2) 2017-10-18T19:16:47.719Z: INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR: 
>   Error: Failed to fetch file
>       at /.../project/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:5164:30
>       at ReadFileContext.callback (/.../p/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:358:29)
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13) (node:43981) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Failed to fetch file (node:43981)
>   [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
>   deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

But I checked the node_modules folder and it's there. I also tried reinstalling it, and other people dont seem to have had problems with the current version of protobuf.js.

Comment: I am having the same issue today. Added answer below to show similar approach and document the output and configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar Issue:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
require("firebase/firestore");
const config = {
  apiKey: "-redacted-",
  authDomain: "-redacted-",
  databaseURL: "-redacted-",
  projectId: "-redacted-",
  storageBucket: "-redacted-",
  messagingSenderId: "-redacted-"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = firebase.firestore();
let ref=db.collection('example').doc('test');
ref.set({test:true});
```

Error in console (Node v6.11.4):

```
Firestore (4.5.2) 2017-10-18T19:48:00.297Z: INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR:  Error: Failed to fetch file
at Error (native)
at /Users/krispy.uccello/Development/devrel/constellation/functions/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:5164:30
at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/krispy.uccello/Development/devrel/constellation/functions/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:358:29)
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:367:13)
```

(node:71564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Failed to fetch file

Database Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**
This issue seems to be related to writes only. I was able to read data from Firestore without issue.

**Update #2:**
I wrote a firebase function to handle the write operation and it worked. The issue could be related the published version of protobuf js that is being installed on the client side. Not sure what version is being used on the Firebase end but it appears to work. See the following function that is invoked through a firebase https trigger - it works and data appears in the firestore database.

```
function writeWorkerProfile(id, data, res) {
  let ref = 
  db.collection('scratch').doc('v1').collection('workers').doc(`${id}`);
  ref.set(data)
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
    res.status(200).send({ok:true})
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      res.status(500).send('Error occurred: Could not write data');
  });
}
```

Comment: What code did you use for reading? Also how did you initiate the firebase https trigger? Thanks! (New to this)

Comment: See the following gists
https://gist.github.com/kuccello/d68f671ad396b8741bcdd47a7218044b https://gist.github.com/kuccello/4d367cc011aa941a456f60a01826a02f

Comment: Here is the read function:
https://gist.github.com/kuccello/0ae3314bdf4d14128ee41e05cb4b5507